# Error in POI4XPAGES

Tags: excel, apache-poi, runtime-error, xpages

I'm trying to use the POI4XPAGES, installed in my domino designer. I'm trying to run the xpages that comes with the POI example that comes with the installation of POI4XPAGES. I am particularly interested in the upload and processing part of an excel spreadsheet. When I'm running the demo upload function, however, it's giving the error described below. Does anyone know what this is about?

```
Error calling Java constructor 
'biz.webgate.domino.poi.demodb.poweraction.WorkbookUpload ()' 
(java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException).
Unresolved compilation problems: The type 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook can not be resolved. It is indirectly 
referenced from required .class files The import 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook can not be resolved Workbook, HashMap 
<String, String> from the type AbstractPOIPowerAction < Workbook> refers to 
the missing type Workbook

Javascript code

new biz.webgate.domino.poi.demodb.poweraction.WorkbookUpload()
```

Comment: Have you installed POI on the server?  I used updatesite.nsf to install the Apache POI Integration and Library on the server too.

Comment: Not so far I've only installed local, and I'm testing local as well.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the POI4XPages channel is at https://openntf.slack.com not the XPages Slack. I deleted my previous comment...

Answer (score 3):

When you run Domino designer you need to have the used Java libraries also in the Designer runtime directory, not just the plugin into the Domino server. Seems like you might have missed [this step](https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=8UURS7) as described in the [full documentation](https://my.webgate.biz/poi/documentation.nsf/viewdoc.xsp?docid=installguide)

In a nutshell:

- Create a new eclipse update site
- Import the update site from the ZIP file into the eclipse update site
- Add the update site to the Server
- **Add the update site as a widget to the designer client**
- Explore the sample

and restart the Designer (make sure nothing was running after shutdown. Sometimes Eclipse doesn't terminate)

Comment: I installed jars extracted from the ZIP in the <Notes_Data_Directory> \ domino \ workspace \ applications \ eclipse directory location  in the features and plug-ins folders

Comment: In theory that should work (as described here: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_an_XPages_Library_into_Designer ).... however, I suggest follow the instructions outlined in the official documentation and see where it gets you